# I want to create a setup that formats rows based on a specific value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have a running sheet for my expenses.

I would like to setup conditional formatting/Macro/ect. that looks in cells of THE CURRENT MONTH, then any cell that has the text "paid" FOR THE CURRENT MONTH it will apply a gray fill for THE ROW that the cell is in.

EDIT:

SOLVED, thanks to help from @Marc K I ended up with the following formula that I created conditional formatting for each month of the first expense in my list.

`=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Paid",$P4)),MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH($P$3))`

Comment: Current Month, or Current Month AND Year?

Comment: @Marc K  Whichever Excel can track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a table like this

`| Pd Date  | Status  |
|----------|---------|
| 4/1/2015 | paid    |
| 5/7/2015 | denied  |
| 5/11/2015| paid    |
| 5/11/2015| pending |`

You should be able to set conditional formatting using a formula to the row with
`=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("paid",$B2)),MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH($A2))`

Adding a year criteria to filter further.
`=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("paid",$B6)),MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH($A6),YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR($A6))`

The is number function is checking to make sure that "paid" is found in the cell. The remainder is doing combined date comparisons.

Comment: I'm working off a 2010 version of excel, so not sure if this will work for you.

Comment: This seems useful, but my sheet has: [Bill Title][Balance][Payment][.....][Cell I paste "Paid" intro when paid (Arranged L -> R, Jan -> Dec)]  I am trying to color the background of each row gray, where for the current month's cell has "Paid". Ex. The row for Electric (7) has the word "Paid" in the column for May (Q), the row from B7-Q7 turns gray. Then when it becomes June, all rows return to white until the same condition is met for June. Thanks :)

Comment: Using the first half of the formula you provided, I got it to format the background fill of a selection of cells based on the text "Paid" being in a fixed cell. Is there a way to get it to check for the current month (column M-X)?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

It's pretty straightforward actually. Mark the entire column THE CURRENT MONTH, then

```
Conditional formatting
New Rule

Format only cells that contain
```

Here you can choose for example "`Specific text`", where you set a condition `="paid"`, next to it you can define how to format cells.

Comment: I tried selecting the row and setting a rule to format the row, if the cell said paid. I have never done this before and I'm missing something. When you say to mark the entire column the current month, what are you referring to doing? Also, I don't want just the cell that the text "paid" is in highlighted, but the entire row that the cell is in.